# Windows 10 UWP, NavigationView Update Selected MenuItem on BackNavigation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigationview

I am writing an windows 10 UWP app and want to use the NavigationView in combination with the `BackRequested` event handler to handle back navigation, however "GoBack" doesn't update the selected menu item, this means when I use the backbutton the selected menu item doesn't change. to fix this I have created an ugly foreach loop that selects the `MenuItem` on back navigation using a tag. This works but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this,
`GoBack` doesn't fire the `ItemInvoked` or `SelectionChanged` event so I can't seem to be able to use those.

MainPage.xaml

```
  <NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                CompactModeThresholdWidth="1920" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1920"
                ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
                SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged"
                Loaded="NavView_Loaded"
                Canvas.ZIndex="0">

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="HomeNavItem" Content="Home" Tag="home">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE10F;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                       FontSize="28"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Welcome"/>
                            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>

    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>

</NavigationView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs snippet:

```
        public MainPage()
    {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       // initial page for ContentFrame
       ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
       ContentFrame.Navigated += MainFrame_Navigated;
       SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += MainPage_BackRequested;

    }

    private void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tag = null;
        if (!ContentFrame.CanGoBack) return;
        e.Handled = true;
        ContentFrame.GoBack();
        if (ContentFrame.SourcePageType == typeof(HomePage))
        {
            tag = "home";
        }

        foreach (var navViewMenuItem in NavView.MenuItems)
        {
            if (navViewMenuItem is NavigationViewItem item)
            {
                if (item.Tag.Equals(tag)) item.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }               
    }

    private void MainFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = ((Frame) sender).CanGoBack
            ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible
            : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NavigationView` menu items themselves could do other action than just navigation, hence the control has "no reason" to track the back navigation and update accordingly. What you can do however to set the tag of your `MenuItems` and use it for both `ItemInvoked` navigation and for back navigation.

`NavigationView` menu items XAML would include a `Tag` that exactly matches the target page type name:

```
<NavigationView Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="First" Tag="FirstPage">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="1" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Second" Tag="SecondPage">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        ...
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

Now within the `MainFrame_Navigated` method we can do the following:

```
//get the Type of the currently displayed page
var pageName = AppFrame.Content.GetType().Name;
//find menu item that has the matching tag
var menuItem = AppNavigationView.MenuItems
                         .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                         .Where(item => item.Tag.ToString() == pageName)
                         .First();
//select
AppNavigationView.SelectedItem = menuItem;
```

You can also use similar approach for `ItemInvoked` handler:

```
var invokedMenuItem = sender.MenuItems
                            .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                            .Where(item => 
                                 item.Content.ToString() == 
                                 args.InvokedItem.ToString())
                            .First();
var pageTypeName = invokedMenuItem.Tag.ToString();
var pageType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType($"{PageNamespace}.{pageTypeName}");
AppFrame.Navigate(pageType);
```

Where `PageNamespace` is a string constant with the name of the namespace where your `Pages` are stored. You can use `nameof` to keep it up to date safely, for example:

```
private const string PageNamespace = nameof(MyApp.Pages);
```

I have prepared a sample project that demonstrates these suggestions, you can check it out [on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2018/tree/master/BackTrackingNavigationView).

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you.  One needs to be careful in handling {PageNamespace}.{pageTypeName} if he has pages under different folders.  I include the folder name in the tag (e.g. ViewGroup1.Page1, ViewGroup2.Page1...) and prefix them with the app's namesspace to get the type.

Comment: Awesome answer, especially going to the trouble of writing an entire sample application.  One note for anyone using the GitHub application though, remember to add code to the NavigationView_ItemInvoked method to handle the NavigationVeiw Settings button behind clicked/tapped.  You can enclose the code that's currently there inside the else block of `if(args.IsSettingsInvoked)
            {
                //Handle settings click
            }else { //Place existing github code here  }`